# Why do I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException iterating a List?

Tags: python, scala

I am trying to convert a python code to scala. I am new to Scala, it is a very different language than python.

I have tried converting all the python functions to Scala like so:

```java
def legalMoves(board: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    val moves = List[List[Int]]()
    for ((piece, pos) <- board.zipWithIndex) {
      val jumpmove = pos + (piece * 2)
      val move = pos + (piece)
      if (piece != 0) {
        if (!((jumpmove < 0) || (jumpmove >= board.size))) {
          if (board(jumpmove) == 0) {
            val t = List(board)
            t.updated(pos, 0)
            t.updated(jumpmove, piece)
            moves :+ t
          }
        }
        if (!((move < 0) || (move >= board.size))) {
          if (board(move) == 0) {
            val t = List(board)
            t.updated(pos, 0)
            t.updated(move, piece)
            moves :+ t
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return moves
  }

  def evalAll(current: List[List[Int]], target: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    val next = List[List[Int]]()
    for (a <- current) {
      val n = legalMoves(a)
      for (q <- n) {
        val t = List(a)
        t :+ q
        if (q == target) {
          return t
        }
        next :+ t
      }
    }
    return next
  }

  def solve(start: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    var temp = List(start)
    val end = start.reverse
    while (temp.last != end) {
      temp = evalAll(temp, end)
    }
    return temp
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(solve(List(1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1)))
  }
```

This is what I get as an error when I try to run it:

```
[error]        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:791)
[error]        at org.mq.frogsandtoads.Main$.legalMoves(Main.scala:6)
[error]        at org.mq.frogsandtoads.Main$.$anonfun$evalAll$1(Main.scala:34)
[error]        at org.mq.frogsandtoads.Main$.$anonfun$evalAll$1$adapted(Main.scala:33)
[error]        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[error]        at org.mq.frogsandtoads.Main$.evalAll(Main.scala:33)
[error]        at org.mq.frogsandtoads.Main$.solve(Main.scala:51)
[error]        at org.mq.frogsandtoads.Main$.main(Main.scala:57)
[error] Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Aug 23, 2019, 8:18:35 PM
```

I don't understand what is wrong. Would love to be put in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of *Scala*!

Things can certainly be a little confusing at times, but with a little perseverance, anything is possible. :-)

The cause of the exception was an invalid list index value. (In case it's not apparent, if you have a list with `n` elements, you'll get that exception if you attempt to access any member with an index outside the range `[0, n - 1]`.)

Unfortunately, your "solution" just adds another layer of lists, which fixes the symptoms, but I don't think it addresses the problem. Still, your code correctly outlines a series of boards with one solution, for the given problem.

However, this particular problem has two solutions for any given board, and they're mirror images of each other. There are some other rules that are characteristics of the solutions, say for a game with `F` frogs and `T` toads:

- The total number of jumps in each solution is `F x T`.
- The total number of slides in each solution is `F + T`.
- Consequently, the total number of moves in each solutions is `(F x T) + F + T`.

I tried to make sense of your code, but I gave up; I couldn't get my head around it! :-) Instead, I coded up a solution that is a little more detailed, but it produces more comprehensible output (and, hopefully, you'll understand it OK, too).

BTW, *Scala* `List`s are not really meant to be used in the way you tried. Each `List` is essentially made up of two elements: a `head` (which is the first element in the list) and a `tail` (which is a `List` containing the remaining elements). The value `Nil` represents an empty list. This sets up a recursive relationship that allows us to iterate through a `List` performing actions on successive head elements as required. Consequently, it doesn't perform too well when you need to look up an element by its position in the list (such lookups have efficiencies of the order `O(n)`). An `Array` is far better at that (efficiency of order `O(1)`).

Also, the use of while loops and `var`s is discouraged in *Scala*, because there are better approaches available. To illustrate this, I've re-written your program to take advantage of *Scala*'s *functional programming* capabilities:

```
package org.mq.frogsandtoads

import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Main {

  // Moves are to the right or to the left, so let's capture directions as
  // a hierarchy of directions.
  //
  // (This is nicer than using integer values.)
  //
  // A trait is like an abstract class that takes no class arguments. A case
  // object is an object that can be used in pattern matching, which we'll see
  // shortly. We can't create a Direction, but we can create Right & Left.
  trait Direction {

    // An index multiplier. 1 = to the right, -1 to the left.
    //
    // This is an abstract value, overridden in base classes.
    val multiplier: Int
  }

  case object Left extends Direction {
    override val multiplier = -1
  }

  case object Right extends Direction {
    override val multiplier = 1
  }

  // Let's capture frogs, toads and the hole as a hierarchy of board elements.
  trait Element

  // Frogs and toads are movable elements, holes are not.
  trait MovableElement extends Element {

    // Direction this element can move in.
    val direction: Direction
  }

  // Frogs can only move to the right.
  case object Frog extends MovableElement {
    override val direction = Right
  }

  // Toads can only move to the left.
  case object Toad extends MovableElement {
    override val direction = Left
  }

  // The hole cannot be moved (directly).
  case object Hole extends Element

  // A "board" is now a vector of elements. So let's define a type for that.
  //
  // Arrays are preferable to Lists because they support efficient element
  // retrieval given an index. Alas, they're also mutuable collections, which
  // we typically prefer to avoid. So instead we'll use a Vector, which is
  // immutable, if a little slower than an Array. I'm using it to demonstrate
  // how  immutable collections are used.
  type Board = Vector[Element]

  // Let's capture the turns as either Slides (1 position) or Jumps (2
  // positions).
  trait Turn {
    val positions: Int
  }

  case object Slide extends Turn {
    override val positions = 1
  }

  case object Jump extends Turn  {
    override val positions = 2
  }

  // A move, which applies only movable elements, consists of a turn a
  // direction, and the resulting board. We'll use a case class for this.
  final case class Move(turn: Turn, direction: Direction, board: Board)

  // A solution is now a list of moves. This type can also be used for
  // potential solutions.
  type Solution = List[Move]

  // A game has the specified number of frogs and toads.
  final class Game(frogs: Int, toads: Int) {

    // Sanity checks.
    require(frogs > 0, s"Number of frogs must be positive: $frogs")
    require(toads > 0, s"Number of toads must be positive: $toads")

    // Size of the boards in this game: the frogs + the toads + 1 for the hole.
    val boardSize = frogs + toads + 1

    // Create an initial board, in which we have all the frogs, a hole then all
    // the toads. Tabulate takes, as its first argument, the size of the board.
    // The second argument determines what element goes into each slot.
    private val initialBoard: Board = Vector.tabulate(boardSize) {i =>

      // If i (a 0-based index) is less than frogs, then this is a Frog.
      if(i < frogs) Frog

      // If it's equal to frogs, then it is the Hole.
      else if(i == frogs) Hole

      // Otherwise, it's a Toad.
      else Toad
    }

    // Create a final board. This happens when we have all the toads, the hole,
    // then all the frogs. We can obtain it by reversing the initial board.
    private val finalBoard: Board = initialBoard.reverse

    // Validate a board. This checks whether we have the right number of frogs,
    // toads and a hole. It returns true if the board is valid, false
    // otherwise.
    private def validate(board: Board): Boolean = {

      // An initial count, as a 3 value tuple: the number of frogs, holes and
      // toads respectively. Each count in the tuple is accessed by the member
      // references _1, _2 and _3.
      val initialCounts = (0, 0, 0)

      // Perform a fold left, where we iterate through the board counting the
      // types of element it contains. The first argument is the initial count
      // and the second argument is a function that takes two arguments, a
      // count tuple and an element. The fold operation calls this function for
      // each element of the board in turn, providing the new count for each
      // one.
      val finalCounts = board.foldLeft(initialCounts) {(counts, element) =>
        element match {
          case Frog => (counts._1 + 1, counts._2, counts._3)
          case Hole => (counts._1, counts._2 + 1, counts._3)
          case Toad => (counts._1, counts._2, counts._3 + 1)
        }
      }

      // Check that the final counts match our expected counts, returning the
      // result.
      finalCounts == (frogs, 1, toads)
    }

    // Use the validation function to ensure that our initial and final boards
    // are valid.
    assert(validate(initialBoard), s"Initial board is invalid: $initialBoard")
    assert(validate(finalBoard), s"Final board is invalid: $finalBoard")

    // Determine if the board is done, that is, if we have all the toads, then
    // the hole, then all the frogs.
    private def isFinished(board: Board): Boolean = board == finalBoard

    // Determine if a position is valid. Return true if it is, false if not.
    private def isValidPosition(i: Int): Boolean = i >= 0 && i < boardSize

    // Determine if a move is possible on a given board, returning the
    // successful move wrapped in Some, or None if it cannot be made. The
    // result is of type Option.
    //
    // board is the current board before making the move, i is the position of
    // the piece and turn is the action being attempted.
    private def makeMove(board: Board, i: Int, turn: Turn): Option[Move] = {

      // Sanity checks.
      assert(validate(board), s"Intermediate board is invalid: $board")
      assert(isValidPosition(i), s"Invalid move position: $i")

      // Examine the element at the specified board position.
      board(i) match {

        // If the element is a movable element, then we need to examine its
        // turn type.
        case me: MovableElement => {

          // Get the direction of this move, based upon the element at the
          // specified postion.
          val dir = me.direction

          // Get the target position for the move. It if's invalid, we cannot
          // make this move.
          val target = i + dir.multiplier * turn.positions
          if(!isValidPosition(target)) None

          // Otherwise, if the element at the target position is not a Hole,
          // then we cannot make this move.
          else if(board(target) != Hole) None

          // If this turn is a jump, and the element we're attempting to jump
          // over is the same type as this element, then we cannot make this
          // move.
          else if(turn == Jump && board(i + dir.multiplier) == board(i)) None

          // OK. We can make this move. Create a new board by replacing the
          // hole at the target position with this element, and replace this
          // element with a Hole.
          else {
            val newBoard = board.updated(target, me).updated(i, Hole)

            // Sanity check to ensure that the new board is valid.
            assert(validate(newBoard), s"New board following $turn, $dir is invalid: $newBoard")

            // Create the move we're considering making.
            val move = Move(turn, dir, newBoard)

            // Return the move wrapped in Some.
            Some(move)
          }
        }

        // Otherwise, it's a hole, so it can't be moved.
        case _ => None
      }
    }

    // Evaluate the current state of play.
    @tailrec
    private def validMoves(solutions: List[Solution],
    partialSolutions: List[(Solution, Board)]): List[Solution] =  {

      // If there are no more partial solutions, then we're done. Return all
      // the solutions found.
      if(partialSolutions.isEmpty) solutions

      // Otherwise, try to perform another set of moves for each partial
      // solution.
      else {

        // For each partial solution, try all possible moves, filtering out
        // those that could not be made.
        val updated = partialSolutions.flatMap {

          // Split the current partial solution into a list of moves and a board.
          case (ms, b) => {
            for {

              // Check each position on the board.
              i <- 0 until boardSize

              // Check each turn at each position.
              t <- List(Slide, Jump)

              // Determine the result of attempting to make this move on the
              // partial solution's last board.
              r = makeMove(b, i, t)

              // Filter out those moves that failed, retaining only those that
              // are defined (i.e. not None).
              //
              // Note: if there are NO valid moves for this board, then this
              // will filter out the initial partial solution.
              if r.isDefined

              // Retrieve the move.
              m = r.get

              // For the result, create a Solution by adding the move to the
              // current list of moves (note that we have to build it in
              // reverse) and updating the resulting board.
            } yield (m :: ms, m.board)
          }
        }

        // Now partition the partial solutions by looking at the resulting
        // board: any that match the final board are complete solutions.
        val (completed, newPartialSolutions) = updated.partition {
          case (_, b) => isFinished(b)
        }

        // Determine the new list of completed solutions by processing the
        // completed list. "map" operates on each member of completed, changing
        // the result.
        val newSolutions = completed.map {

          // Reverse the set of moves so that it is the right way around.
          // Discard the completed board.
          case (moves, _) => moves.reverse
        }

        // Perform another iteration.
        validMoves(newSolutions, newPartialSolutions)
      }
    }

    // Solve the game, finding all possible sequence of moves that result in
    // the final board. Because there are more than one solution, we'll return
    // a list of all the solutions found.
    //
    // Initially, we have no solutions. Our only partial solution consists of
    // no moves and the initial board.
    def solve: List[Solution] = validMoves(Nil, List((Nil, initialBoard)))
  }

  // Main function.
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Create a game with 3 frogs and 3 toads and find the solutions.
    val solutions = new Game(3, 3).solve

    // Now report the number of solutions and detail them.
    println(s"Number of solutions found: ${solutions.size}")
    solutions.foreach {sol =>

      // For each solution, output a summary of the solution.
      println()
      println("Solution begins:")
      println()
      val moves = sol.size
      val (slides, jumps) = sol.map(_.turn).foldLeft((0, 0)) {(c, t) =>
        t match {
          case Slide => (c._1 + 1, c._2) // Increment number of slides.
          case _ => (c._1, c._2 + 1)     // Increment number of jumps.
        }
      }
      assert(slides + jumps == moves,
        s"slides ($slides) + jumps ($jumps) != moves ($moves)")

      println(s"Total moves: $moves (slides: $slides, jumps: $jumps)")
      println()
      println("Moves:")
      sol.foreach(println)
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Number of solutions found: 2

Solution begins:

Total moves: 15 (slides: 6, jumps: 9)

Moves:
Move(Slide,Right,Vector(Frog, Frog, Hole, Frog, Toad, Toad, Toad))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Frog, Frog, Toad, Frog, Hole, Toad, Toad))
Move(Slide,Left,Vector(Frog, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Hole, Toad))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Frog, Frog, Toad, Hole, Toad, Frog, Toad))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Frog, Hole, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad))
Move(Slide,Right,Vector(Hole, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Toad, Frog, Hole, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Hole, Frog, Toad))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Hole))
Move(Slide,Right,Vector(Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Hole, Frog))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Toad, Frog, Toad, Hole, Toad, Frog, Frog))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Toad, Hole, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Frog))
Move(Slide,Left,Vector(Toad, Toad, Hole, Frog, Toad, Frog, Frog))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Toad, Toad, Toad, Frog, Hole, Frog, Frog))
Move(Slide,Right,Vector(Toad, Toad, Toad, Hole, Frog, Frog, Frog))

Solution begins:

Total moves: 15 (slides: 6, jumps: 9)

Moves:
Move(Slide,Left,Vector(Frog, Frog, Frog, Toad, Hole, Toad, Toad))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Frog, Frog, Hole, Toad, Frog, Toad, Toad))
Move(Slide,Right,Vector(Frog, Hole, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Toad))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Frog, Toad, Frog, Hole, Frog, Toad, Toad))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Hole, Toad))
Move(Slide,Left,Vector(Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Hole))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Hole, Toad, Frog))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Frog, Toad, Hole, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Hole, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog))
Move(Slide,Left,Vector(Toad, Hole, Frog, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Toad, Toad, Frog, Hole, Frog, Toad, Frog))
Move(Jump,Left,Vector(Toad, Toad, Frog, Toad, Frog, Hole, Frog))
Move(Slide,Right,Vector(Toad, Toad, Frog, Toad, Hole, Frog, Frog))
Move(Jump,Right,Vector(Toad, Toad, Hole, Toad, Frog, Frog, Frog))
Move(Slide,Left,Vector(Toad, Toad, Toad, Hole, Frog, Frog, Frog))
```

There's going to be a lot there that you might not understand, right away. I would encourage you to visit the [*Scala* API documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.9/) to lookup some of the details you're unsure of.

Comment: I just can't begin to comprehend how you wrote such a detailed explanation accompanied by 300+ lines of code with comments. Thank so much, I now have a much better understanding of Scala.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution by editing the code like so (there are too many changes to list):

```java
package org.mq.frogsandtoads

object Main {
  def legalMoves(board: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    var moves = List[List[Int]]()
    for ((piece, pos) <- board.zipWithIndex) {
      val jumpmove = pos + (piece * 2)
      val move = pos + (piece)
      if (piece != 0) {
        if (!((jumpmove < 0) || (jumpmove >= board.size))) {
          if (board(jumpmove) == 0) {
            var t = board
            t = t.patch(pos, List(0), 1)
            t = t.patch(jumpmove, List(piece), 1)
            moves = moves :+ t
          }
        }
        if (!((move < 0) || (move >= board.size))) {
          if (board(move) == 0) {
            var t = board
            t = t.patch(pos, List(0), 1)
            t = t.patch(move, List(piece), 1)
            moves = moves :+ t
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return moves
  }

  def evalAll(
      current: List[List[List[Int]]],
      target: List[Int]
  ): List[List[List[Int]]] = {
    var next = List[List[List[Int]]]()
    for (a <- current) {
      val n = legalMoves(a.last)
      for (q <- n) {
        var t = a
        t = t :+ q
        if (q == target) {
          return List(t)
        }
        next = next :+ t
      }
    }
    return next
  }

  def solve(start: List[Int]): List[List[List[Int]]] = {
    var temp = List(List(start))
    val end = start.reverse
    while (temp.last.last != end) {
      temp = evalAll(temp, end)
    }
    return temp
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(solve(List(1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1)))
  }
}
```